# Separate list into single elements within list in Python

Tags: python, list, character

I have a code at the moment that takes a line from a .txt file and then turns it into a list, with the whitespace stripped.

Looks like this:

```
fd = open(filename,'rU')
chars = []
for line in fd:
    chars.append(line.strip())

return chars
```

The output looks like this:

```
['TTTTT', 'TTHHT', 'HHTHT', 'HHHHH', 'THTHT', '']
```

What I want to do here is turn the out put to look like this:

```
[['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['T', 'T', 'H', 'H',  'T',] etc...]
```

I want to separate them into single elements, but also keep them within their original lists.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the sub-lists? You know you can iterate over the strings, and index into them, the same way, yeah? You just can't modify them in-place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do this, as you can do almost anything you can do with a `list` with a `str` -- except change it.

Assuming you have a good reason, you probably want to change your loop to

```
for line in fd:
    chars.append(list(line.strip()))
```

or after the loop,

```
chars = map(list, chars)
```

Will do it. It will run `list` on each item in `chars`.

On Python 2, it will make a `list` out of the result.

On Python 3, you'll need to do

```
chars = list(map(list, chars))
```

or

```
chars = [list(sublist) for sublist in chars]
```

if you want it back as a list-o-lists.

Comment: Combining this all into one-ish line: `with open(filename, 'fU') as f: return [list(line.strip()) for line in f]`. Or, if you want to rely on reference counting to close your file, `lambda filename: [list(l.strip()) for l in open(filename, 'fU')]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 a = ['TTTTT', 'TTHHT', 'HHTHT', 'HHHHH', 'THTHT', '']
>>> 
>>> b = [list(x) for x in a]
>>> b
[['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['T', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T'], ['H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T'], ['H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H'], ['T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T'], []]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Python list comprehension will solve your problem:

```
lVals = [list(x.strip()) for x in open(filename,'rU').readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = ['TTTTT', 'TTHHT', 'HHTHT', 'HHHHH', 'THTHT', '']
>>> map(list, data)
[['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['T', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T'], ['H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T'], ['H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H'], ['T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T'], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one liner

`map(list, list(open('test.py')))`

or

`[list(a) for a in list( open('fileName.txt', 'rU') )]`

but this is best done in two lines like so

```
fileHandler = open('file.txt')
fileData = map(list, list(fileHandler))
```